# How old might Emmy Noether be in this picture?

Tags: mathematicians, biographical-details

I have not found bibliographic data to show what age Noether was in this picture:[image: Emmy Noether relatively young]
And I cannot estimate well either by her clothes or her face.

Can anyone here help me?

In the past I have known people to date photographs by the clothes, in ways that often checked out very well.  And this style looks fairly distinctive to me. But I am not now in touch with any of those people.

Comment: The [History of Women's Fashion](https://glamourdaze.com/history-of-womens-fashion/1900-to-1919) section headed "Modes of Dress - 1900-1909" suggests that 1905/6 might be a good guess based on a bowed collar, absence of a hat, and belted waistline.  Noether is clearly in her 20s in the photograph and a date of 1905 would place her age at 23.  Prior years tend to look more formal and a few years later (down the article) do not match at all.

Comment: Also: [wikimedia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Noether.jpg) dates the photograph “before 1910” with [source](https://www.flickr.com/photos/maaorg/5506847067/) “Courtesy of Drs. Emiliana and Monica Noether” — apparently the [wife and daughter](https://history.uconn.edu/emeritus-faculty/emiliana-pasca-noether/) of Emmy’s nephew Gottfried Emanuel Noether. Google finds Monica’s email.